# Testing JavaFX application with JUnit

Tags: java, button, testing, junit, javafx

I've got rather simple JavaFX application:

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    final int[] i = {0};
    FlowPane root = new FlowPane();
    root.setPadding(new Insets(40, 40, 40, 40));
    Button btn1 = new Button("Button 1");
    Button btn2 = new Button("Button 2");
    Label lbl = new Label("Output");
    Label lbl1 = new Label("Counter here");

    btn1.setOnAction(event -> { lbl.setText("Button 1 is pressed");
    lbl1.setText(""+ i[0]++);});

    btn2.setOnAction(event -> { lbl.setText("Button 2 is pressed");
        lbl1.setText(""+ i[0]++);});

    root.getChildren().addAll(lbl, btn1, btn2, lbl1);
    root.setId("root");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 100, 150));
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

How can I test it with JUnit framework? What aspects of the app should be tested? 
I just want to understand how JavaFX applications are usually subjected to test.

Answer (score 3):

Well... you can perform various tests. Your choice. Logic is being tested with `JUnit`. If you application connects to some external system, you can perform integration tests. However, I think that your question is more related about testing JavaFX UI (functional testing) If so, you can use something like a [TestFX](https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX).

Comment: Yes, I can easilly test the logic of the app. However, what I asked was how to test JavaFX UI with JUnit (if it's possivle at all).

Comment: @Anton Testing of UI is not a subject of unit tests. It's a subject of functional tests.